# Class inside namespace and set function outside in C++

Tags: c++, function, namespaces

In this task i need to set and get number of soldiers outside of class and namespace (and call it in main properly)

```
namespace GeneralStaff
{

class Troops
{
private:
    int nSoldiers;

public:
    string name;
    string rank;
    
    Troops(string _name, string _rank, )
    {
        name= "Unknown";
        rank= "RankUnknown";
    }
};

} // namespace GeneralStaff
```

> This is outside of class and function

```
void GeneralStaff::Troops setSoldierN(int n)
{
    nSoldiers= n;
}
```

In main:

```
GeneralStaff::Troops;
    Troops.setSoldierN(10);
```

I know that i need proper object declaration in main (source) and problem is with function set.

Comment: just create object resolving with namespace name

Comment: If you did not have the namespace you would still need an object.

Comment: That is a problem if I do GeneralStaff::Troops t1, it's wrong and i'm asking here because i dont know how to properly make an object and call function properly

Comment: `setSoldierN(int n)` needs to be a class member. And `void GeneralStaff::Troops setSoldierN(int n)` needs to be `void GeneralStaff::Troops::setSoldierN(int n)` or inside namespace GeneralStaff { void Troops::setSoldierN(int n) {} };

Comment: I need global set function

Comment: Then you need a global Troops object. I would say this is however a bad design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To define a method of the class outside the class, just use the scope resolution(::) operator. But for defining a function outside the class, you need to declare it in the class itself, which you have not done. Check the following code, it should work:

```
namespace GeneralStaff
{
    class Troops{
        private:
            int nSoldiers;

        public:
            string name;
            string rank;
            void setSoldierN(int x);

            Troops(string _name, string _rank)
            {
                name= _name;
                rank= _rank;
            }
    };
}

void GeneralStaff::Troops::setSoldierN(int n){
    nSoldiers= n;
}
```

Also, I have initialized *name* and *rank* according to the values passed in the constructor, because there is no need of passing them if you want to initialize the variables with a fixed value.

And the object in the main function should be created as follows:

```
GeneralStaff::Troops troop("John", "2");
    troop.setSoldierN(10);
```

Comment: Yes I did that implementation needs to be outside my mistake, what about object in main.

Comment: Something like: `int main() { GeneralStaff::Troops myTroops{"Name","Rank"}; myTroops.setSoldierN(10);}`

Comment: I added Troops(){}, if i call like this GeneralStaff::Troops troop("John", "2");
It says i dont have proper constructor

Comment: Change `Troops(string _name, string _rank, )` to `Troops(string _name, string _rank)`

Comment: Now i get unknown name and rank

Answer (score 0):

A external function should be defined as friend to access prive members of a class:

```
class Troops
    {
        friend void GeneralStaff::Troops setSoldierN(GeneralStaff &gs, int n);

         ...
};
```

and setSoldierN need to get an instance of Staff class to change its nSoldiers

```
void GeneralStaff::Troops setSoldierN(GeneralStaff &gs, int n)
{
    gs.nSoldiers= n;
}
```

Comment: But it is not a external function. He just want to define it outside the class definition I guess.